# the function on Model doesn't work well

Tags: php, yii, substr

I wanna ask about validation on Yii. I've put my validation on model just like this :

```
public function CekDigit($attribute,$params)
    {
        $subject=substr($attribute,0,2);
        $pattern=$this->string2;
        if ($subject!==$pattern)
            {
                $this->addError($attribute, $params['message']);
                return false;
            }
    }
```

while I ran that, it turned on the error message, even the condition was true.
I meant, when I put the same string (which is matched) was still got an error. 
How can I fix it so that it becomes valid condition?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post example values for `$attribute` and `$this->string2`?

Comment: $attribute has 7 digits, but I take just 2 digits (the beginning). And I wanna match it with $string2 (2 digits)

Comment: It solved by this code

    `public function CekDigit($attribute,$params)`
     `{`
      `$subject=substr($this>getAttribute($attribute),0,2)`
      `$pattern=$this->string2;`
      `if ($subject!==$pattern)`
       `{`
        `$this>addError($attribute,$params['message']);`
        `return false;`
       `}`
      `else return true;`
     `}`

Comment: Put that as an answer and accept it in due time. That is the SO way.

Answer (score 0):

instead of **if ($subject!==$pattern)**

you might want to use **if (strcmp($subject,$pattern) == 0)**